# Myhashmap extends hashmap and overrides hash function

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

If I have a class myhashmap which extends hashmap and then I override the function hash to return a constant then how is insertions and lookup in my map affected?

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't provide a hash function but calls `hashCode()` (and `equals()`) on the keys. So implement your method there and read up on the numerous documentation on how lookups and insertions are done, especially the part on collisions which will play an important role if you use a constant hash (in that case the question would be: why use a HashMap in the first place?).

Comment: If that was possible, and if you did that, you would transform the map into a big linked list, and the map operations (i.e. insert and lookup) would become O(N) rather than O(1).

Comment: yes so basically if i override the hashCode() and return constant in MyHashMap extends HashMap class then it has no effect?

Comment: No. It will have the same effect: turning your map into a linked list, and making it O(N). You need to read about how a HashMap works.

Comment: But if the key class which is inserted into myhashmap has its own overwritten hashcode function then it should not convert to a list?right?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. The only thing you could override in `Myhashmap` would be the `hashCode()` for `Myhashmap` itself. This wouldn't affect performance of `Myhashmap` ifself. On the other hand, `HashSet<Myhashmap>` and `Map<Myhashmap, ?>` would behave pretty horrible.

To understand this, you have to understand the basic functionality of a `HashSet` (or `HashMap`, but the principle is the same). Both work by distributing `Object`s into buckets according to their hash:

```
List<T>[] buckets = new List<>[bucketnum];

void add(T t){
    List<T> l = buckets[t.hashCode() % buckets.length];
    if(!l.contains(t))
        l.add(t);
}
```

Now while this implementation is kept oversimplistic and shouldn't be used in actual code, it shows one thing pretty clearly: a `HashSet` is fast, because it uses buckets. But making the `hashCode()`-method return a constant will lead to a `HashSet` where all values are inserted into a single bucket. Or in other words: just throw that `HashSet` away and use a `List`, as runtime won't change at all in the best case, or might even be worse due, since a `HashSet/-Map` introduces overhead compared to a `List`. E.g. `HashSet/-Map` increases the bucket-number if a certain load-factor is reached, which requires additional resources.

EDIT:
This goes a bit more in depth, and while it's interesting as it shows a different implementation of `HashSet/-Map`s, it's not necessary to understand, as it's just an expansion of the above introduction to hash-datastructures and should be considered as a footnote. Actually there is another option: [Collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). In that case there doesn't exist an `List` to store objects that share a certain hash-bucket. Instead the algorithm searches for available buckets in a certain pattern. This could be linear, quadratic, etc..

E.g.:

```
T[] buckets;

boolean add(T t){
    int index = t.hashCode() % bucketnum;

    for(int i = 0; i < bucketnum; i++){
        if(buckets[(i + index) % bucketnum] == null){
            buckets[(i + index) % bucketnum] = t;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This code uses a linear collision-strategy to deal with colliding hashes (two objects `a`, `b`, such that `a.hashCode() % bucketnum == b.hashCode() % bucketnum`). While this implementation shows a bit different behavior and requires a different load-factor, a proper hashing-function is still required, as otherwise performance will be even worse than with the bucket-list approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in returning constant value in hash function. If you do this, than hashMap will turn into simple linked list.

`tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]` here n is the size of map.
If your hash is constant than its result will be always constant and get/put function take O(N) time.